# Inserting a record in an SQL Server database using session in aspnet with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, session

I'm trying to insert a record into a SQL Server 2014 database using ASP.NET with C#.

I have implemented a session for my gridview data, and I'm trying to insert that session into the database, but when I click the button "book", only the top URL changes:

[image: URL bar pic]

Database:

[image: My database pic]

The record isn't getting inserted into the database nor my Label (Errorm) is changing to gg.

`.aspx` file:

```
<%@ Page Title=""
    Language="C#"
    MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master"
    AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="hotels.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="Hotel_Mangement.hotels" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="hotels" runat="server">
    <div class="destinations">
        <div class="destination-head">
            <div class="wrap">
                <h3>Hotels</h3>
            </div>

            <!-- End-destinations -->
            <div class="find-place dfind-place">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="p-h">
                        <span>FIND YOUR</span>
                        <label>HOTEL</label>
                    </div>

                    <!-- strat-date-picker -->
                    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
                    <script>
                        $(function () {
                            $("#<%= txtstart.ClientID %>").datepicker();
                        });
                    </script>
                    <!-- /End-date-picker -->

                    <!-- strat-date-picker -->
                    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
                    <script>
                        $(function () {
                            $("#<%= txtend.ClientID %>").datepicker();
                        });
                    </script>
                    <!---/End-date-piker---->

                    <div class="p-ww">
                        <form>
                            <span> City or Area</span>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="dl1" runat="server" class="dest" required="This field cannot be blank">
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Location</asp:ListItem>

                                <asp:ListItem>Mumbai</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Goa</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Delhi</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Ahmedabad</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Jammu</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Jharkhand</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Kerala</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Bhuj</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Bengaluru</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Kalyan</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList><br />

                            <br /><span> Check-in</span>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtstart" runat="server" class="date" required="This field cannot be blank"></asp:TextBox>

                            <span> Check-out</span>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtend" runat="server"  class="date" required="This field cannot be blank"></asp:TextBox><br /> <br />
                            <span> Number of rooms</span>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="dlrooms" runat="server" required="This field cannot be blank">
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select number of rooms</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList><br /><br />

                            <span> Number of members</span>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="dlmumbers" runat="server" required="This field cannot be blank">
                                <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Select number of members per room</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <br /> <br />

                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!----//End-find-place---->

        </div>
        <div class="criuse-main">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="criuse-head1">
                    <h3>CHEAPEST HOTELS</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1"
                           runat="server"
                           ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegisterConnectionString15 %>'
                           SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [hotels_main]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >

            <ItemTemplate>
                <div ID="div1" runat="server">
                    <div class="criuse-main" >
                        <div class="wrap">
                            <div class="criuse-grids">
                                <div class="criuse-grid">
                                    <div class="criuse-grid-head">
                                        <div class="criuse-img">
                                            <div class="criuse-pic">
                                                 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImagePath") %>'  Height="350px"  width="1000px"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="criuse-pic-info">
                                                <div class="criuse-pic-info-top">
                                                    <div class="criuse-pic-info-top-weather">
                                                        <p>33<label>o</label><i>c</i><span> </span></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="criuse-pic-info-top-place-name">
                                                        <h2><span><%#Eval("hotel_location") %></span></h2>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="criuse-pic-info-price">
                                                    <p><span>Starting From</span> <h4><%#Eval("price") %> $</h4></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="criuse-info">
                                            <div class="criuse-info-left">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a class="c-hotel" href="#"><span> </span><%#Eval("rooms_available") %></a></li>
                                                    <li><a class="c-air" href="flight.aspx"><span> </span> Air Ticket</a></li>
                                                    <li><a class="c-fast" href="#"><span> </span> Guest per room:<%#Eval("max_guest") %></a></li>
                                                    <li><a class="c-car" href="#"><span> </span> Car for All transfers</a></li>
                                                    <div class="clear"> </div>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="clear"> </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="criuse-grid-info">
                                        <h1>    <a href="hotels_main.aspx?id=<%#Eval("hotel_id") %>" ><%#Eval("hotel_name") %></a></h1>

                                        <p><%#Eval("s_desc") %> </p>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <center>
            <div>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" class="myGridClass" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#7C6F57" />
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#666666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#E3EAEB" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#C5BBAF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F8FAFA" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#246B61" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D4DFE1" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#15524A" />

                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HotelName">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblhotelname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("hotel_name") %>' ></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HotelLocation">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblhotellocation" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("hotel_location") %>' ></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblprice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("price") %>' ></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>

                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                <br />

                <form>
                    <asp:Button ID="book" runat="server" Text="Book now" class="d-next" OnClick="book_Click" />
                </form>

                <asp:Label ID="lprice" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lcheckin" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lcheckout" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lmembers" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lrooms" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>

                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Errorm" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </center>

    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

`.aspx.cs` code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Hotel_Mangement
{
    public partial class hotels : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=RISHIK\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Register;Integrated Security=True");

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.Visible = false;
            /* div1.Visible = true; */
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from hotels_main";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

            con.Close();
            book.Visible = false;
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query =
                "select hotel_name, hotel_location ,price from hotels_main where hotel_location='" +
                dl1.Text + "' ";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.Visible=true;

            con.Close();

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                Label1.Visible = true;
                Label1.Text = "No data found";
                book.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
               /* div1.Visible = true;*/

                Label1.Visible = false;
                book.Visible = true;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataRow dr;
                dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("HotelName", typeof(String)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("HotelLocation", typeof(String)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new System.Data.DataColumn("Price", typeof(String)));
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    Label lblhotelname = (Label)row.FindControl("lblhotelname");
                    Session["hotelname"] = lblhotelname.Text;
                    Label lblhotellocation = (Label)row.FindControl("lblhotellocation");
                    Session["hotelocation"] = lblhotellocation.Text;
                    Label lblprice = (Label)row.FindControl("lblprice");
                    Session["price"] = lblprice.Text;
                    dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr[0] = lblhotelname.Text;
                    dr[1] = lblhotellocation.Text;
                    dr[2] = lblprice.Text;
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
                Session["check_in"] = txtstart.Text.ToString();
                Session["check_out"] = txtend.Text.ToString();
            }
        }

        /*private void SendGridInfo()
        {
            }
            Session["GridData"] = dt; Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
        }  */

        protected void book_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            string insertQuery = "Insert into hotelbook_details values('" + Session["USER_ID"].ToString() + "','" + Session["hotelname"].ToString() + "','" + Session["hotelocation"].ToString() + "','" + Session["check_in"].ToString() + "','" + Session["check_out"].ToString() + "','" + Session["price"].ToString() + "')";

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, con);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            Errorm.Text = "gg";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not store `SqlConnection` or anything else that implements [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx). That's just asking for bugs and leaking resources. Read the link I provided.

Comment: mate, leave and errors its a college project, people here dont know about Sql injection attack so this Idisposble is too big for them to understand, really thanks for the info tho

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a college project or not. Do you ever plan to program after college? I'm not telling this so you can get an A on your project. It's important. And it has nothing to do with SQL Injection Attacks, though those are important too. You are leaking resources. Leaving hard to diagnose bugs in your code. Being inefficient as well. Take the time to learn now, don't let it be something that bites you in the ass and embarrasses you after you graduate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the `<form> ..... </form>` tag in aspx. As I am using a master page I don't need it.

After removing all the form tags, it worked all fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not saving? Have you checked your database?

**Change your load page to:**

```
if (IsPostBack == false){
     GridView1.Visible = false;
     /* div1.Visible = true; */
     con.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     cmd.CommandText = "select * from hotels_main";
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     da.Fill(dt);

     con.Close();
     book.Visible = false;
}
```

> When you click a button it will reload the form load. The code above will prevent it from loading when doing a post-back, that is, clicking a button.

Comment: Did made the changes as you said, still cant get the records stored in database, and yes I'm checking database

Comment: You have an error in most likely your sql query.  If you are running release opposed to debug for example it will skip the error and exit the method.  Put you book button code in a try catch block and step trough the code to make sure you do not have any errors. It is also not the best idea to use your connection as a global variable and is best as a read only property. This way you can instantiate a new connection only when you need it.